# Calculate duration for each task in AWS Express state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

AWS state machines emit log events like `TaskStarted` and `TaskSucceeded` which can be used to calculate the total duration of a particular task. However, this makes it challenging to obtain the duration using Log Insights or even by creating a Lambda-backed Cloudwatch subscription (since `TaskStarted` and `TaskSucceeded` log events can be in separate Lambda invocations).

Ideally, I would like to have this duration emitted as a metric. E.g. if the state machine task calls to a Sagemaker Endpoint "X" with parameter `TargetModel=abc.tar.gz`, I'd like to have a metric named `Endpoint_X_abc` with the total duration of this task.

What is the proper way to do this?